# Two-way scroll on magic trackpad on Windows 7

Tags: windows, trackpad

Using the bootcamp drivers, I am able to use an Apple Magic Trackpad on my PC running Windows 7. Everything seems to work fine. When I'm in Google Chrome (and other applications), I can use the two-finger swipe to scroll left and right. However, when I try to use the two-finger scroll (left and right) on Adobe Photoshop/InDesign/etc, it doesn't work at all (scrolling up and down works fine). Any ideas?